# Spring Micrometer: Shipping Metrics to an AWS ElasticSearch Instance

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, aws-elasticsearch, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I'd like to ship Micrometer's default actuator metrics (JVM memory and the like) to  an AWS ElasticSearch instance and visualize the data in Kibana.

I think I'm setting it up correctly but I'm getting no data in Kibana.

Here's my configuration:

`compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-elastic:latest.release'`
`management.metrics.export.elastic.host=https://${url}.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com`

URL is hard-coded in the application, I just removed it here. The url I'm using is from my AWS Dashboard for the ES domain, where it lists:

`Endpoint: https://${url}.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com`

But using this configuration I haven't been able to get any data to show up in Kibana.

Other considerations: I know Micrometer has access to this data because I have a Prometheus endpoint set up where I can see the actuator info. It's just a question of how it's supposed to be sent to elastic.

Resources:

http://micrometer.io/docs/registry/elastic

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-export-elastic

https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/implementations/micrometer-registry-elastic/src/main/java/io/micrometer/elastic/ElasticConfig.java

Comment: I am not instantiating ElasticConfig or ElasticMeterRegistry because I think I don't need them if I am not registering custom metrics. Is this an incorrect assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by updating Spring-Boot to 2.1.0 version.

Micrometer-elastic is supported as of Micrometer 1.1.0, which is included in the Spring-Boot 2.1.0 release.

Comment: In the project's build.gradle file: check for springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'

Comment: you can accept your own answer to show that your question is solved.